# Python - quick sort - maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

This is my code:

```
from random import randint

def quick_sort(sort_me):
    if len(sort_me) < 2:
        return sort_me

    pivot = sort_me[0]

    this = lower = upper = []

    for x in sort_me:
        if x < pivot:
            lower.append(x)
        elif x > pivot:
            upper.append(x)
        else:
            this.append(x)

    return quick_sort(lower) + this + quick_sort(upper)
```

And all I can see  in terminal is this:

```
File "sorts.py", line 19, in quick_sort
  return quick_sort(lower) + this + quick_sort(upper)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I think something is wrong with `this` list but I don't know what. Help!

Comment: You could always take some tips from existing implementations such as - http://hetland.org/coding/python/quicksort.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this = lower = upper = []
```

Assignment never creates copies in Python. This line doesn't create 3 lists; it creates 1 list, and makes `this`, `lower`, and `upper` all refer to that list. Make 3 lists.

```
this = []
lower = []
upper = []
```

Comment: I knew about this but didn't hit my mind. Now I feel stupid. Thanks for help. I'll accept your answer asap. But, is there any way to make 3 empty lists in 1 line?

Comment: `this, lower, upper = [], [], []`

Comment: Thanks user2357112 :)